# How to interpret SISS error message of Package Validation Error: an OLE DB record is available Hresult: 0x80040E14

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Sometimes when creating an SSIS data transfer job I get a scary-looking error along the lines of:

> Package Validation Error.  Additional information: Error at ... SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred.  Error code: 0x80040E14.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client."  Hresult: 0x80040E14.  Description: "Statements(s) could not be prepared."

It continues in this fashion.  Where is the actionable part of the message?  Why this strange error code when the SSIS job worked previously and I hardly changed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This complex-looking error message occurs for me when there's some simple failure in one of my SQL statements, or I'm referring to an object that doesn't exist.

The actionable part of the error message occurs in the second `"Description: ..."` line.

In the example above, the next line was `Description: "Invalid object name 'DataLake.dbo.MyTable'.".`  I had not selected the correct connection manager when creating that table, so it was created in another database, and then when one of my SSIS package steps failed to find it where expected, it threw this long error message.

Most of the message, with `0x80040E14` and all the rest at the end about failing validation and errors during task validation can be ignored for the purpose of fixing it.